# Antd Table: autosize scroll:y to parent

Tags: reactjs, antd, ant-design-pro

I'm using Antd table and I'm using `scroll: {y:...}` to have the table contents scrollable. I'd like to have the table auto-size to fit the parent and be responsive to re-sizes. ('auto' sizes the control to fit all its contents, which is not what I need.) Currently I'm just hacking a constant height that works when the app is maximized on my primary monitor. I've tried several CSS overrides, but I can't seem to get this to work as desired.

Comment: Hi @TheLazyDogsBack, have you found a solution for this? I am currently facing the same.